# Manually constructed matrix debugging

Tags: javascript, svg, matrix, transform

I am trying to see if I can correctly achieve the matrix value when I manually construct a transform matrix. Element with `id=One` has transform elements provided already. For the element with `id=Two` I have manually constructed the transform element with exact same transform element as `id=One`. However, when I log the consolidated matrix for both they are not idential.

How can I achieve the same consolidated matrix value for `id=Two` as it is for `id=One`. What am I doing wrong?

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#one')
    .transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix);

const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const testElement = document.querySelector('#two');
const transformList = testElement.transform.baseVal;
let matrix = svg.createSVGMatrix();
matrix = matrix.translate(-247.890625, -60).scale(1, 0).translate(247.890625, 60);
const transform = svg.createSVGTransformFromMatrix(matrix);
transformList.appendItem(transform);
transformList.consolidate();
console.log(matrix);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SVG Transformations</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
      <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
      <g class="test" transform="translate(400,300)">
        <text id="one" x="10" y="60" stroke="red" fill="red" font-size="45px" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(-247.890625,-60)scale (1,0)translate(247.890625,60)" style="text-rendering: geometricprecision; font-size: xxx-large;">F</text>
        <text id="two" x="10" y="60" stroke="green" fill="green" font-size="45px" text-anchor="start" style="text-rendering: geometricprecision; font-size: xxx-large;">X</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SVGMatrix.scale(s)`, unlike `DOMMatrix.scale(sx, sy)` takes only one parameter. The factor is applied uniformly to both dimensions. You need to use [`SVGMatrix.scaleNonUniform(sx, sy)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#__svg__SVGMatrix__scaleNonUniform).

Unfortunately, for now browsers are only implementing SVG 1.1 when executing `svg.createSVGMatrix()` and return a `SVGMatrix`. With SVG 2, the return value would be a `DOMMatrix`, and your code would have worked.